# VBA input formula into cell error

Tags: vba, excel

Confused about a Run-Time error I am receiving. I'm building a tool that changes formulas by state. No problem building the Excel If functions, but when I clear the below I run into an issue at **Range("C13")...**

```
Sub clearICRs()

    Range("B2").Value = "(Select State)"
    Range("C4:C8,C11,C18,C20,C24").Value = "0"
    Range("C13").Value = "=IF($B$2=""Arkansas"",'Taxes & Fees'!$F$29,IF($B$2=""Connecticut"",IF($C$11<=50000,0.0635,0.07),IF($E21=TRUE,$F21,""Input Tax %""))"
    Range("C15").Value = "=IF($B$2=""California"",""Input CVR"",IF($E15=TRUE,$F15,""Input Fees""))"
    Rows("16:17").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Range("C21").Value = "=IF($B$2=""Connecticut"",IF($C$11<=50000,0.0635,0.07),IF($E21=TRUE,$F21,""Input Tax %""))"
    Range("C23").Value = "=IF($B$2=""Arkansas"",'Taxes & Fees'!$F$29,IF($E23=TRUE,$F23,""Input Fees""))"

End Sub
```

However, if **IF($B$2=""Arkansas"",'Taxes & Fees'!$F$29,** is removed from **Range("C13")...** the code works. What I need help understanding is why I run into an error on **C13** but not on **C23**?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another ) to the end of the formula

```
Range("C13").Value = "=IF($B$2="Arkansas",'Taxes & Fees'!$F$29,IF($B$2="Connecticut",IF($C$11<=50000,0.0635,0.07),IF($E21=TRUE,$F21,"Input Tax %")))"
```